# How i can add comma after each entered number only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i add comma automatically after each entered number.
For example like : 1,2,3,4

If i add number 5 after 4 so it should be separated with the comma.
Below is my code.

```js
function addComma(txt) {
    txt.value = txt.value.replace(",", "").replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, "$1,$2");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" onkeyup="addComma(this);" />
```

the comma is separating after a few numbers. I require an auto-add comma after each number has been entered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I change your RegEx. See below example.

```js
function addComma(txt) {
    txt.value = txt.value.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" onkeyup="addComma(this);" />
```